# C# - Need to add one offset to two addresses that leave up to my value

Tags: c#

I had a question regarding C# and memory editing/reading, I have these readers:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 CloseHandle(IntPtr hProcess);
```

---

These are my fields and initialization of methods I have made:

```
unsafe
{
    //Process Fields
    Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("ac_client").FirstOrDefault();
    IntPtr openProcess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
    IntPtr Handle = process.Handle;
    IntPtr pBaseAddress = (IntPtr)process.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
    int processID = process.Id;

    //Game Offsets and Pointers
    IntPtr pGame = new IntPtr(0x400000);
    IntPtr pPlayerClass = new IntPtr(0x0011E20C);
    int oPlayerHealth = 0xF8;

    //Adding Pointers and Offsets
    IntPtr aGameAndHealth = IntPtr.Add(pGame, oPlayerHealth);
    IntPtr aGameAndPlayerClass = IntPtr.Add(pGame, oPlayerHealth);
    IntPtr PlayerHealth = IntPtr.Add(aGameAndHealth, (int)aGameAndPlayerClass);
    IntPtr gGame = IntPtr.Add(pGame, (int)pPlayerClass);
    IntPtr gPlayerHealth = IntPtr.Add(gGame, oPlayerHealth);

    //RPM Fields
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
    int r = -1;

    //RPM
    ReadProcessMemory(openProcess, (int)PlayerHealth, buffer, buffer.Length, ref r);
    int HealthValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

    //Console Prints
    Console.WriteLine("[INFO] Process ID: " + processID);
    Console.WriteLine("[INFO] Process Handle: " +  string.Format("{0:x}",Handle));
    Console.WriteLine("[INFO] ac_client.exe Pointer: 0x" + 
        string.Format("{0:x}", (int)pBaseAddress));
    Console.WriteLine("[INFO] Player Base Address: 0x" + 
        string.Format("{0:x}", (int)pPlayerClass));
    Console.WriteLine("Test: " + HealthValue);
    Console.WriteLine("[+] Updating Health!");
    //Console.WriteLine("[INFO] Current Health: 0x" + 
    //    Convert.ToInt32(PlayerHealth + oPlayerHealth), 0);

    WriteToMemory(openProcess, (int)PlayerHealth, 100);

    //WriteToMemory(process, (Convert.ToInt32((int)(pBaseAddress + 
    //    oPlayerOffset) + oPlayerHealth)), 1000);
    Thread.Sleep((int)1.08e+7);
}
```

---

The address that my code gives for the Base Address is 0x400000, the player class(I had assumed this because it also gives me coordinates, View Matrix etc.). I do not want to add 0x400000 and my player class together, I want them to do what CE is doing, I can't really explain it so here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

What do I do to point w/ two pointers and add one offset? Can I do this? Do I have to open the read the process memory of the base address, read the buffer I get when I run my `byte[]` buffer through it and repeat that for every address until I get somewhere in terms of pointing to 100 which is my goal.

Useful INFO: 
 ac_client.exe Pointer: 0x400000 - This equals "ac_client.exe" and stays static.
 Player Class Address: 0x11e20c - 0011E20C I found this, just thought I would print it for debugging purposes.

Feel free to edit my code, I like it the way it is, but if you can make it easier feel free to tell me what I should do/do it :D

Comment: "I can't really explain it so here is a screenshot" - I have no idea what this is trying to show.

Comment: So 40000 is the base address and 0011E2C is the player class, the offset is f8. I want to write to this: (400000 and 011E2C) + F8

Comment: so you want a pointer to `0x00E4A638`?

Comment: Yes. But that value is dynamic, right now it is '00E8A540'

Comment: 0x40000 is the base address by default of the module code, but it gets randomized in modern apps for security purposes. I suggest you to learn about memory allocation in the process first to understand which regions of memory are executable, read-only, etc.

Comment: The thing that you are doing is fun! I've done this long time ago - a  universal app that searcher for specific values and changes them - e.g. search for 34 ammo and change it to 99999. Good luck :)

Comment: No I know how to to do that. I just need to know how to apply it in C# I know alot about memorys, calls adds movs etc. I just need to know how to apply it :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference each level of the pointer and then add the offset by using the classic `FindDMAAddy()` function

```c#
public static IntPtr FindDMAAddy(IntPtr hProc, IntPtr ptr, int[] offsets)
{
    var buffer = new byte[IntPtr.Size];
    foreach (int i in offsets)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, ptr, buffer, buffer.Length, out var read);

        ptr = (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        ? IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0)), i)
        : ptr = IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0)), i);
    }
    return ptr;
}

var healthAddr = FindDMAAddy(hProc, (IntPtr)(0x400000 + 0x11e20), new int[] { 0xf8 });

System.Console.WriteLine("Last Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

Console.WriteLine("Health address " + "0x" + ammoAddr.ToString("X"));
```

You should also never hard code any addresses, you should use `GetModuleBaseAddress()` to get the address of all modules at runtime.